# How Show Loading form whenever Application Loads or Fetch Large Data from Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**Please help to implement this code whenever my application loads while database operations**

I've code like this

```
Private bgw As New BackgroundWorker
Public Sub showLoading()
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    
    AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_doWork
    AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgw_Complete
    
    If Not bgw.IsBusy = True Then
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub closeLoading()
    If bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True Then
        bgw.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bgw_doWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim loadingScreen As New frmLoading
    
    
    loadingScreen.Show()
    
    While True
        If Not bgw.CancellationPending Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Else
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit While
        End If
        End While
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub bgw_Complete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        Dim lstFrm As New List(Of frmLoading)
        lstFrm = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of frmLoading)()
        
        If lstFrm.Count > 0 Then
            For Each frm As frmLoading In lstFrm
                frm.Close()
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Please help me how to call this method to multiple forms whenever needed**

Comment: I suggest that you forget that and use [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?869567) instead. This will reduce the code clutter in your existing form and it also works better because it's a modal dialogue. The form it displays includes a `ProgressBar` that can show real progress or not, but you can modify modify it to display an animated GIF in a `PictureBox` or whatever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be loadingScreen.ShowDialog().

Use loadingScreen.Show() as .ShowDialog() blocks the execution as long as the Dialog stays open.